# Seaborn plot : Adjust overlapping (x,y) labels / text

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have text annotation for each (x,y) point on a scatter plot. However, the labels overlap and it looks kinda messy. Is there a way to adjust text for seaborn texts? I have seen some libraries / python packages that do this for `matplotlib`.

https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"one": [1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
                   "two": [3,6,4,3,8,2,5],
                   "label":['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='one', y='two', data = df1)

for line in range(0,df1.shape[0]):
    ax.text(df1.one[line]+0.04, 
            df1.two[line], 
            df1.label[line], horizontalalignment='left', 
            size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

Comment: The x's to be annotated are too close together, so changing the position from 0.04 to about 0.2 would be an improvement for this amount of data. I don't think I need to introduce a new library.

Comment: They still appear to be overlapping.

Comment: The dataframe I have is a sample, the real data is fairly large with about 90 points. So need a solution that generalizable.

Comment: I didn't bother to comment if I had the information needed to answer your question. The person answering can only make decisions based on the information given.

Comment: Not to give you more work to do, but this would probably be a good use case for Plotly's Dash or Express libraries because you could use a combination of rollovers (built-in for both), filtering (Dash via callbacks), and area expansion.